# Python, if a condition is met, ignore step

Tags: python, wlst

I am somewhat of a beginner but I am working on wlst script that basically, if the server_name starts with soa_sever(n) but if soa_server2+ add a two minute sleep.

```
def rollstartCluster(): 
    connectAdmin()
    serverList=cmo.getServers()
    domainRuntime()
    for server in serverList:
      if server.getCluster()!=None and server.getCluster().getName()==CLUSTER_NAME:
           serverRuntimeMBean = getMBean('/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/'+server.getName())
           serverState = serverRuntimeMBean.getState()
           server_name=server.getName()
           shutdown(server.getName(),'Server','true',120,force='true',block='true')
           counter=1
           if server_name.startswith('soa_server') and counter > 2:
             print " 2 Minute wait before starting Instance"
             systime.sleep(120)
           start(server.getName(),'Server', block="true") 
           counter= counter +1
           exit()
```

I added the counter so that when it a soa_server2+ adds a two minute wait.
I am not able to work as expected, any help

Comment: Every time you go through your loop you reset `counter = 1`

Comment: You have a problems with indents... or is it just a problem of question text formatting?

Comment: @Stepan, is the text formating.

Comment: @Iguananaut, thank you, I didn't see that I was resetting the counter

Comment: Why the `exit()`? Testing for `None` should be done using `is`, not `==`.

Comment: @Alexander I am using wlst script so I connect to the AdminServer so I close the connection hence I could use disconnect() or exit()

Answer (score -1):

You can use the library time:

`import time`

and then write:
`time.sleep(2*60)`

Comment: While this is a good suggestion, since `systime.sleep` isn't a default Python function, it still doesn't solve his issue that he isn't seeing it reach that sleep call  since he doesn't ever set counter to be anything that would trigger that call. Also, `time.sleep(n)` sleeps for `n` _seconds_, not minutes.

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb, The problem here is that the weblogic.time package is shadowing the stdlib time module. So, when you try to import time, I get an error so I have to use 
    import time as systime
    systime.sleep(120)

Comment: Thank you everyone, I was able to fix the issue and again, @Iguananaut for your quick response and helpful input.